# Animate new data insertion in core-plot (iOS)

Tags: ios, core-animation, core-plot, scatter-plot

I am trying to animate the "drawing" of new data using a CPTScatterPlot objects.

I am now looking at the RealTime example that you can find [here](https://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/browse/#hg%2Fexamples%2FCorePlotGallery) in the examples subdirectory. It is one of the example of the CorePlotGallery. Make sure you use the iOS one.

This RealTime plot is pretty simple: it injects some random data in the graph every second.
What I am trying to accomplish is to animate the drawing of the line so that it seems that the line is being drawn realtime.

If you take a close look at the example, you will notice that "segments" appear in the chart as soon as new data is inserted into it. How can I animate the "creation" of those segments?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until this is added natively to Core Plot (see [this outstanding issue](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=536)), use a timer to animate the line. Each time the timer fires, use the `-reloadDataInIndexRange:` method to update the last point on the line, moving it closer to the final value each time.

Comment: I'll definitely try and report back :)

Comment: Can you elaborate on the method? I would like the line to appear without the choppiness. Best if it's "grown" from the previous point.